# struts2 s:select value ognl expression

Tags: struts2, ognl

In Struts2 tutorial for [`s:select`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/select.html) tag I've seen:

```
<s:select label="Pets"
       name="petIds"
       list="petDao.pets"
       listKey="id"
       listValue="name"
       multiple="true"
       size="3"
       required="true"
       value="%{petDao.pets.{id}}"
/>                          ^  ^
```

and my question: why `value="%{petDao.pets.{id}}"`? why not simply `value="%{petDao.pets.id}"`? what do those trailing curly braces mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an [OGNL list projection](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html#Projecting_Across_Collections) to get all the `id` values as a list from `petDao.pets`, meaning all values in this `<s:select>` will be pre-selected.

Comment: +1, once again I've forgotten about some of OGNL's capabilities. (Which is ironic, since I was once unofficially crowned King of OGNL on the S2 mailing list because of the weird stuff I'd do with it.)

Comment: (Although I'm not convinced that it's (a) a good example, or (b) correct in the context of the tutorial. I'm still going to remove it to avoid confusion, since it also isn't recognized by IntelliJ at least, leading to even *more* confusion.)

Comment: Agree, it shouldn't be in tags examples.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary; I suspect it was the result of an error in the tag's source file.

It works with it, but isn't needed, will fail IDE validation (if the IDE supports S2 and/or OGNL, e.g., IntelliJ), and I've made a note to update.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: It is perfectly legal OGNL expression.

Comment: @AndreaLigios No, Aleksandr is correct; it's a list projection--an OGNL feature I've forgotten about more than once. It may or may not be correct *behavior* in the context of the tutorial, IMO it seems unlikely it's the intention, but don't know. I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Interesting ! You could edit instead of deleting, you or AleksandrM should add some more details (from http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html and http://ojitha.blogspot.it/2011/07/ognl-part-5-projection.html for example),

Answer (score 0):

The principal reason is because %{} syntax is used to force OGNL evaluation where Struts would otherwise be treating the value as a String literal.

For example,

`<s:property value="name" />`

will look for a name property in the value stack i.e. is a value retrieved by calling getName().

If you wanted to force it to use literal value "name", you will need to use the %{} syntax -

`<s:property value="%{'name'}" />`

Source:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/420711/Struts/Struts

Comment: misunderstanding: i know what is `%{}` but i don't know the difference between `...pets.{id}` and `...pets.id`

Comment: The link provided has more to do with distinguishing between items on the value stack and items in the value stack context, e.g., that require a `#` to reference. There's nothing involving string literals here, if anything, a reference to the S2 or OGNL docs would make more sense (delta the misunderstanding, anyway).

Comment: ohhh i'm sorry, honestly I don't know why but could be by the grammar of language, greetings!