# set multiple default value in select tag in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

How can I set multiple default value using select tag in struts2. For e.g I have list of names with "nameA, nameB, nameC". I want that these three names will be selected by default. I can populate a list but struggling to set multiple default value.

```
<s:select id        = "name" 
          size      = "5" 
          name      = "nameForm.nameIds" 
          cssStyle  = "width:365px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;"
          list      = "name.nameList" 
          listKey   = "id" 
          listValue = "displayName" 
          multiple  = "true" 
></s:select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `value` attribute of `<s:select>` tag. And because you are using bean to generate `<s:select>` values you need to create list of bean properties that you used in `listKey` attribute. In your case a list of `id`-s.

```
<s:set var="idsList" value="{'id1','id2','id3'}" />
<s:select list="name.nameList" listKey="id" listValue="displayName" multiple="true" value="%{#idsList}" />
```

In order to select all use your list with OGNL projection selecting id-s in it.

```
<s:select id        = "name" 
          size      = "5" 
          name      = "nameForm.nameIds" 
          cssStyle  = "width:365px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;"
          list      = "name.nameList" 
          listKey   = "id" 
          listValue = "displayName" 
          multiple  = "true" 
          value     = "%{name.nameList.{id}}"
></s:select>
```

Comment: Each parameter could have multiple values, thus could be set by default. +1, not tested.

Comment: @Java_NewBie: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14565387/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

Point to your `List` of names from the `value` attribute...

```
<s:select id        = "name" 
          size      = "5" 
          name      = "nameForm.nameIds" 
          cssStyle  = "width:365px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;"
          list      = "name.nameList" 
          listKey   = "id" 
          listValue = "displayName" 
          multiple  = "true" 
          value     = "%{yourList}"
></s:select>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea. But I want to highlight as well, that these are selected. Please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: For e.g like when I click on a value it highlights it, but how can I do it in the above case without clicking it. I want to show then that these are highlighted by default. Thanks

Comment: Exactly like above; yourList must be a List of id of selected names populated in the Action, and exposed with a getter; I supposed that was already clear :|

Comment: Andrea, I have tried this. value = "%{name.nameList}", but I cannot see the values highlight with blue.

Comment: name.nameList is your FULL list, you need to point (from `value`) to *another* sub-list of selected IDs (the same entity used in listKey); try, if you still have problems, update your question with the Java code, and I'll edit the answer...

Comment: @Java_NewBie you really should have upvoted both the question, and accepted AlenksandrM one... meh